# Ruby on Rails automatic string extraction for translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization, rubygems

I am trying to automatically extract strings from ruby views **.erb** files to **config/lang/** files for example **en.yml**

Is there some updated alternative to this?

http://zigzag.github.io/2009/12/17/get-your-local-rails-application-ready-for-i18n.html

It is supposed to be a gem tool that will extract strings if used like this:

```
ready_for_i18n <you view path> <target path>
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a number of gems that do this. One list of such gems is maintained on the [i18n-tasks wiki](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/wiki#extract-plain-strings-to-i18n-keys):

> - [Slimkeyfy](https://github.com/phrase/slimkeyfy) extracts plain strings from Slim views and Rails Controllers.
> - [haml-i18n-extractor](https://github.com/shaiguitar/haml-i18n-extractor)
>     automates string extraction from HAML.
> - [i15r](https://github.com/balinterdi/i15r) for ERB and Haml.
> - [i18n-html_extractor](https://github.com/ProGM/i18n-html_extractor) another extractor for ERB with an interactive mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try [i18n-tasks](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) gem

```
$ i18n-tasks add-missing
```

Comment: this one is just for adding the translations that already extracted